# ServiceStack add information to logout response status

Tags: servicestack, logout

ServiceStack add information to logout response status

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a relative url to redirect to by specifying `?continue` on the queryString, e.g:

```
/auth/logout?continue=/logout-success
```

which will redirect to `example.org/logout-success` page which you can implement as normal.

Rather than specifying it on the queryString you can force it to redirect to a specific url by overriding the `LogoutUrlFilter`, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...,
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new CredentialsAuthProvider {
            LogoutUrlFilter = (auth, url) => "/logout-success"
        },
    });
```

#### Logging out with Ajax

Another option is to logout with Ajax which gives you more flexibility, e.g. you can notify the user logged out on the same page (i.e. without redirecting):

```
$.getJSON("/auth/logout", function () {
    $("#status").html("You successfully Signed out");
});
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to add information (successful/failed) to the returned response status? Would prefer to display dynamic information (successful logout/failed logout) rather than creating static pages. If it is a failed logout then we still need to access the response status to decide which page we are going to redirect to. Thanks.

Comment: @user5506787 it's unlikely to fail since it's just removing the session from the Cache, but when Auth's fail the redirect contains a `#s` param for success and a `#f=ErrorCode` for failed requests. You can change to use `?s=` queryString if `Config.AddRedirectParamsToQueryString=true` [more info in the forums](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/logout-path-s-1/1297/3?u=mythz).